# Why can't I change disk with command prompt as administrator?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I was struggling to do basic operations on disk, an `init` command couldn't find Z: and the usual `Z:` command didn't let me change to disk Z:

After a while I realized I only had this problem with the command prompt as administrator and the regular cmd worked fine.

Why is that? I was using admin because I was installing something, is it bad behavior to always use cmd as admin for installing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `Z:` is a mapped network drive or something created by using `subst`. In that case that only affects your user account, not the administrator account. If they are both separate you'll end up not having a `Z:` drive under the administrator account.

Answer (score 1):

Mapped drives are stored in the user token. Administrators have two - a normal user one and an administrator one. You can only map a drive once. If you map as a normal user it is unavailable to the user when elevated (and vice versa). You cannot map the drive a second time.

Comment: This is correct for the default policy, which strictly separates the device mappings for the two logon sessions. But a policy can be enabled that links them. In "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System", create a DWORD named "EnableLinkedConnections" with a value of 1. Then restart the system.